Android Studio debug not showing runtime elements in component tree when debugging
I'm trying to debug my application which currently is just using a button to add a text field.  In the screenshot I have clicked the button twice, creating two new "Ingredient" text boxes.  However in the component tree view, only the original text box is shown and the runtime text boxes are not.  I have verified through breakpoints that all three text boxes are in the layout, but they do not show in the inspector.  I'm not sure how to get them to show in the debugger as that would be significantly easier to debug and format.  Any help on how or what I may be doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

